# Eigenvalues of the integral operator $f \to \int_{0}^{1}(x+y)f(y) \, dy$, $L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

> Find the eigenvalues of the integral operator $L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$,
> $$f \mapsto \Big( x \mapsto \int_0^1 (x+y)f(y)dy \Big).$$

I think that the eigenvalues are the solutions to the equation $x^2-x-1/12=0$.

How did I arrive to this conclusion:

The image is polynomials up to degree $1$. Thus we only have to consider images of $x+c$. $\int_0^1 (x+y)(y+c) \, dy=\lambda(x+c)$ solving this we get $1/3+c/2=\lambda c$ and $1/2+c=\lambda$ which yield $\lambda^2-\lambda-1/12=0$ . Is this correct? Also since this operator is self-adjoint, does that mean the operator norm is one of those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is correct. For the second part the argument is not correct. A self adjoint operator on an infinite dimensional space may have lots of points in the spectrum other than eigenvalues and eigenvalues don't determine the norm.  However this operator has one dimensional range and hence it is compact. For compact operators the only point in the spectrum are eigenvalues together with $0$. It is true that $\|T\|=\max \{|\lambda|: \lambda^{2}-\lambda -\frac 1  {12}=0\}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention it is compact. That makes sense, thank you!